# Как выровнять фон по середине контейнера bootstrap'а?

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap, svg, inkscape

Как можно выровнять фон у контейнера (`fluid`), чтобы он полностью отображался.
Есть картинка (SVG) - волна, если задавать через `bg-url`, то либо верх, либо центр , либо низ картинки видно.
Первый скрин. то что у меня получается, 2 скрин, то что нужно. Но так как картинка в SVG не смогу её загрузить в инет, чтобы получить ссылку, поэтому там другая картинка, но проблема также сохраняется с ней. А именно выравнивание картинки с верхом и низом.

[image: скриншот что у меня]
[image: то что нужно]

Мой код:

```css
.ribbon_first {
    background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/16/11/45/blue-waves-2317606_960_720.png) no-repeat;
   background-size: 100%;
   background-position: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container-fluid ribbon_first">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 whomСourse-about">
        <h2>Курс идеально подойдет</h2>
        <p>Тем, кто хочет продвигать бренды в Инстаграм, используя все его преимущества</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц 

background: url(img/ribbon_second.svg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 100%;

Я бы скинул скриншот, но не могу. На скриншоте контейнер полностью залит картинкой. Ни сверхку  , ни снизу волн не видно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то вы хотите картинку фона :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обрезать по контурам картинки розовой волны:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Я покажу технику с помощью которой вы довольно легко сможете сделать это.**

При этом блок будет полностью адаптивный и вы сможете его вставить в любой контейнер, любого приложения.

- Чтобы получить контуры обрезки розовой волны необходимо получить
  `path` контура.

  Для этого пишем небольшой файл svg, чтобы добавить его в векторный
  редактор.  Картинка розовой волны имеет габариты `1331 х 546px`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1331" height="546" viewBox="0 0 1331 546" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivqf1.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

- Открываем этот файл с помощью векторного редактора

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. С помощью инструмента `Рисовать кривые Безье` наносим по контуру узловые точки
2. Инструментом `Редактировать узлы контура` выделяем узлы (они становятся цветными)
3. Делаем узлы Автоматически сглаженными (цифра 3 на рисунке)
4. Рычагами управления узлов добиваемся максимального совпадения контуров с заданной формой

   - Сохраняем файл *.svg
   - Забираем `path`

Ниже контуры этого патча, по этим контурам будет сделана обрезка с помощью `clip-path`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="1331" height="546" viewBox="0 0 1331 546" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" border="1">

  <path d="m0 67.2c0 0 233.3-28.6 350.6-29.2 134-0.7 267.3 19.1 400.9 29.2 82.8 6.3 165.4 15.4 248.3 19.5 54.1 2.7 108.2 2.7 162.3 3.2 56.3 0.6 168.8 0 168.8 0v415.5c0 0-147.2 0.7-220.8 0-55.7-0.5-111.5-0.8-167.2-3.2-63.4-2.8-126.6-9.2-189.9-13-74.6-4.4-149.3-8.7-224-11.4-75.7-2.7-151.5-6.1-227.2-4.9C201.1 474.6 0 489.2 0 489.2Z" style="fill:none;stroke:#000"/>  
  
    <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4W28.png" height="100%" width="100%"/>
</svg>
```

- Теперь полученный контур добавляем в команду `clip-path` и обрезаем с
  помощью него фоновую картинку

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1331 546" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" border="1">
  <defs>
 <clipPath id="cp1">
  <path d="m0 67.2c0 0 233.3-28.6 350.6-29.2 134-0.7 267.3 19.1 400.9 29.2 82.8 6.3 165.4 15.4 248.3 19.5 54.1 2.7 108.2 2.7 162.3 3.2 56.3 0.6 168.8 0 168.8 0v415.5c0 0-147.2 0.7-220.8 0-55.7-0.5-111.5-0.8-167.2-3.2-63.4-2.8-126.6-9.2-189.9-13-74.6-4.4-149.3-8.7-224-11.4-75.7-2.7-151.5-6.1-227.2-4.9C201.1 474.6 0 489.2 0 489.2Z" style="fill:none;stroke:#000"/> 

</clipPath>  
</defs>  
  
    
  <path d="m0 67.2c0 0 233.3-28.6 350.6-29.2 134-0.7 267.3 19.1 400.9 29.2 82.8 6.3 165.4 15.4 248.3 19.5 54.1 2.7 108.2 2.7 162.3 3.2 56.3 0.6 168.8 0 168.8 0v415.5c0 0-147.2 0.7-220.8 0-55.7-0.5-111.5-0.8-167.2-3.2-63.4-2.8-126.6-9.2-189.9-13-74.6-4.4-149.3-8.7-224-11.4-75.7-2.7-151.5-6.1-227.2-4.9C201.1 474.6 0 489.2 0 489.2Z" style="fill:#F783AC;stroke:none"/> 
       <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4W28.png" height="100%" width="100%" clip-path="url(#cp1)"/>
 </svg>
 </div>
```

**Получился полностью адаптивный блок, который работает во всех браузерах, включая `IE` `Edge`**

Можно менять начальные размеры блока изменяя проценты ширины и высоты контейнера.

Comment: Странно, что никто не плюсанул такой труд. Спасибо за подробное пояснение. Всё пошагово. Шикарно.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ваш труд! Это действительно ценная информация, которая, я надеюсь, поможет не только мне! Спасибо вам, все сработало и прояснилось!

Comment: @Anton Brock и я вас благодарю за оценку моего труда. Хочу, чтобы как можно больше людей начали изучать и применять SVG. Ваш пример невозможно было бы сделать полностью на CSS, так как CSS не поддерживает криволинейные контуры.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.ribbon_first {
    background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/16/11/45/blue-waves-2317606_960_720.png) no-repeat;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container-fluid ribbon_first">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 whomСourse-about">
        <h2>Курс идеально подойдет</h2>
        <p>Тем, кто хочет продвигать бренды в Инстаграм, используя все его преимущества</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: почему минус, не хотите прокомментировать?

Comment: Минус поставил не я, но пробывал уже это делать, не сработало.

Comment: @AntonBrock дак а что не так то? Вы нажмите `выполнить код` там же bg растянут, я так понял вам это нужно